# Java method that accepts Consumer<WebElement> as parameter - how to use it?

Tags: java, selenium, consumer

Is there any chance and need to use something like below ?

Could you show examples how to use function thats accepts Consumer WebElement ?

```
private static void methodThatAcceptsConsumer (Consumer<WebElement> consumer) {
    //something here
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Consumer` is an interface. You can implement it as a real class, a named nested class or as lambda.

#### Explicit implementation as class

```
class MyWebElementConsumer implements Consumer<WebElement> {
  @Override
  public void accept(final WebElement element) {
    // do something with element
  }
}

methodThatAcceptsConsumer(new MyWebElementConsumer());
```

#### Pass a lambda

```
methodThatAcceptsConsumer(element -> {/* do something with element */});
```